# Using non-positional parameters in batch

Tags: batch-file

I've got a batch script that drives some load testing, and as such there are a lot of parameters that can be set by the user at run time. These parameters are a mix of mandatory and optional parameters, and as such now that I need to add room for another optional parameter I've kind of painted myself into a corner.

For example, here is what I pass to the batch script to run a normal load test:

```
30run.bat [testrig] [databasetouse] [backupfiletouse] [Collection] [Label] [OPTION1] [OPTION2]
```

For right now the user just passes them in and I call them into variables based on position, checking to see if any are blank before doing anything.

However, I need to make some changes here and add another option, and it is revealing the limitations of positional parameters. Are there any ways to make these arguments non-positional? Or am I doomed to using a whole lot of nested IF's to handle the various options?

Comment: 7 nonpositional (keyword-based?) parameters. If I can count well, leads to 7 `IF`s. Seven is not _a lot_, IMHO. Just handle them in a `FOR` loop, start with `For  %%G in (%*) do ( @echo %%G )`

Comment: JosefZ: The solution may require _much more_ than 7 IF's depending on "the mix of mandatory and optional parameters"...

Comment: Right. I think the real answer is to put my logic into a language more suited for it (Powershell or C# or something). For now, I think I've got some ideas from the below answer and yours, Josef.

Comment: @SeanLong: Thanks for your upvote! Did you saw the edit in my answer? `:)`

Comment: I did, I'm trying to digest what all the ! mean, but I get the general logic of the answer. Forcing the position might actually be a good way to handle this within batch. Which is preferable to a rewrite!

Comment: @Aacini I keep stating that number of nested IFs == number of possible keywords. You are right as well. Additional IFs (sequential, not nested): one to test each mandatory parameter occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this simple method:

```
for %%a in (%*) do set "%%~a=1"
```

This way, you have variables defined for the given parameters, and undefined if not. For example:

```
if defined Collection (
   echo Perform Collection processing
) else (
   echo Collection option not specified...
)
```

**EDIT**: You may also "force position" of these parameters this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "params=%*"
set "options="
set i=0
for %%a in (testrig databasetouse backupfiletouse Collection Label OPTION1 OPTION2) do (
   set /A i+=1
   if "!params:%%a=!" neq "%params%" set "options=!options!!i!"
)
```

For example, if "databasetouse Label OPTION2" was given *in any order*, options variable would have "257" string.

---

**EDIT 2**: *Another method added*

Another way to solve this problem is via *named parameters* (like the ones used in [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6y04sbb(v=vs.84).aspx)). For example, you may define the format of your Batch file this way:

```
30run.bat [/T:testrig] [/DB:databasetouse] [/BF:backupfiletouse] [/C:Collection] [/L:Label] [OPTION1] [OPTION2]
```

Get the parameters like this:

```
for %%a in (%*) do (
   set "param=%%~a"
   if "!param:~0,1!" equ "/" (
      rem Named parameter
      for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ("!param:~1!") do set "%%b=%%c"
   ) else (
      rem Unnamed parameter (option)
      set "!param!=1"
   )
)
```

And use the parameters this way:

```
if defined C (
   echo Collection given: "%C%"
) else (
   echo Collection parameter not specified...
)
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer. IMHO **no words** like "testrig", "databasetouse", "backupfiletouse" etc. could be expected among parameter passed to stript. I'd anticipate (for instance) next script call: `30run.bat 3 data.dbf bckfile OPTION1`. Your code is all nugatory one

Comment: @JosefZ: I see your point. If two optional filenames may appear and just one is given, for example, there is _no way_ to know which one was given and which one not, _unless_ each parameter follows a certain different scheme (the extension, for example). However, in this question all these details were not stated...

Comment: Yes, I see. Then, there should be some rule scheme postulated for supplying parameters, e.g. to omit an optional positional parameter: user must supply an empty string (`""`), except trailing ones